# Angular, callback doesn't change variable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following snippet

This is my **main.html**

```
<h2 class="txtcenter po-2text" style="padding-top:30px">
    {{title}}
</h2>
```

This is my **main.ts**:

```
title: string;

ngOnInit() {
    var self = this;
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('schools/' + this.currentUserId());
    ref.orderByChild('title').on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
        console.log("Title is: " + dataSnapshot.val().title);
        self.title = dataSnapshot.val().title;
    });
}
```

Even though the callback gets fired with some valid data, the title doesn't update automatically. What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please create a working sample of this? You can try creating a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) if possible.

Also try changing the syntax to fat-arrow function syntax and check if that helps.

Try changing your `ngOnInit` like this:

`ngOnInit() {
  const ref = firebase.database().ref('schools/' + this.currentUserId());
  ref.orderByChild('title').on('value', dataSnapshot => this.title = dataSnapshot.val().title);
}`

Comment: @LuigiCapgrosso So `console.log` works fine?

Comment: You may want to check https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Comment: Yes, `console.log` works fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular change detection works based on browser events, since this is a fire base event callback this wont trigger the change detection. So try the following

Import NgZone:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

Add it to your class constructor

```
constructor(public zone: NgZone, ...args){}
```

Run code with zone.run:

```
ref.orderByChild('title').on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
        console.log("Title is: " + dataSnapshot.val().title);
        this.zone.run(() => this.title = dataSnapshot.val().title;)
});
```

Comment: @LuigiCapogrosso :)